# Яндекс карты. control.ListBox Ширина выпадающего списка

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Как задать ширину выпадающему списку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: не могли бы вы предоставить ваш код?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Agapkin/83Lf15a7/9/

Comment: Или средствами css задать  и не мучиться ? Я то думал где то в API можно настроить

Comment: Вы уже задали собственный макет, я думаю, как вы и говорите правильным решением будет задать этому макету ширину средствами css https://jsfiddle.net/nbds2jhc/

Comment: @se0ga ок, это понятно. Вот только никак не могу определиться как сделать: либо в карту впаять фильтр-блок, либо отдельным от карты div контейнером куда запихать фильтр. Смущает юзабилити на моб версии.